# Why LibreOffice Impress displays two items at each key press, instead of one for each?

Tags: click, libreoffice, display, items, openoffice-impress

I created a LibreOffice Impress presentation with a bullet point list on a slide. I defined an animation for it so that each item displays after a new click.

If I start the presentation then the mouse clicks don't do anything. If I press the space bar to simulate mouse clicks then not just the first item is displayed but the first two. The second key press displays the third and fourth item, and so on.

Why are they not displayed one-by-one and why do the mouse clicks not work?

Answer (score 0):

I use a dual monitor Mac configuration. The main screen shows the current and the next slide while the secondary screen shows the current only. That is, the main screen acts as the presenter's display and the secondary one acts as the projector.

If I clicked the mouse then it was on the presenter's screen, that was the reason why the clicks were not detected. When I moved the mouse to the "projector" display then it worked fine.

The space bar works as a fast-forward key, that's the reason why it displays two items each time. You should use Cursor Right to display the items one by one.